# Symmetric Matrix Transpose confusion

Tags: linear-algebra

I am confused about the following work.

Line 2 implies $e^TAx = x^TAe$

But even though A is symmetric, I don't see this.

Likewise, on line 3, the terms $e^Tb$ and $-b^Te$ cancel out. How is this possible?

[image]

Comment: This is because both $e$ and $b$ are vectors, and thus both $e^T b$ and $b^T B$ are the dot product between $e$ and $b$, which is a scalar

Comment: Do you know what the symbols $x^\top A e$ mean? In other words, do you know what sum the symbols are representing?

Comment: @VezenBU That makes sense, I feel so foolish now.

Comment: Also $e^TAx$ is a $1\times1$ matrix, so is equal to its transpose

Comment: @elemelons I understand now, thank you